# Returning file data in JSON format

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have a txt file which has some data in it. I would like to return the data in JSON format.

Why is it that when i do this in my controller, i am able to display the result (but not in JSON format):

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    return new FileReaderClient("C:\\Users\\attsuap1\\Desktop\\1milliontest.txt");
}
```

However when i do this i get the result as: `{"Data":{}}`

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        var result = new FileReaderClient("C:\\Users\\attsuap1\\Desktop\\1milliontest.txt");
        return Ok(new { Data = result });
    }
```

If i just `return result`:

```
 public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        var result = (new FileReaderClient("C:\\Users\\attsuap1\\Desktop\\1milliontest.txt"));
        return result;
    }
```

I do get the data however it is not in the Json format that i want e.g. `{"Data": "Allthecontentinhere"}`. I tried `return Json(result)` that did not work too.

**Here is my FileReaderClient.cs class**

```
public class FileReaderClient : IHttpActionResult
{
    private readonly string filePath;
    private readonly string contentType;

    public FileReaderClient(string filePath, string contentType = null)
    {
        this.filePath = filePath;
        this.contentType = contentType;
    }

    public Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Content = new StreamContent(File.OpenRead(filePath))
            };

            var contentType = this.contentType ?? MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(Path.GetExtension(filePath));
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(contentType);

            return response;
        }, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

How can i edit my code such that the data in the file is returned in JSON format?

Comment: Since you are using WebAPI controllers (vs.  ASP.Net MVC controllers that support `Json()` method) returning reasonable object should automatically produce JSON response. In current state of the post there is no way to know what you want to achieve and why your custom `FileReaderClient` does not represent data you want. Consider reading [MCVE] guidance on posting code and [edit] post to clarify.

Comment: Hi i have included my FileReaderClient class

Comment: Why not using the Server.Mappath-- using paths like "C:\\Users\\attsuap1\\Desktop\\1milliontest.txt" is not a good practice, Okey that may not be the actual reason of you not getting JSON, but still it shows you're not putting 100% in your code.

Comment: I used that at first and got an error `Physical Path given but virtual path expected`. Then i read that Server.Mappath is not needed when i know the path in one of the stackoverflow answers

Comment: If I use your code with `return result`, I get a valid JSON. What do you get? You said: _"I do get the data however it is not in Json format"_.

Comment: I want it to be like `{"Data": "Allthecontentinhere"}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use **'JsonConvert'** / NewtonSoft's JSON.Net Library,

```
var million_records;
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/1milliontest.json")))
{
      million_records= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MillionData>>(sr.ReadToEnd());
}
return million_records;
```

Hope this helps.
--- N Baua

Comment: Hi thanks for helping me. So should i replace the codes in my FileReaderClient.cs to this?

Comment: And will these codes display the data that is in my `1milliontest.txt` file?

Comment: Ideally it should, however that something, you need to try. Yes , you can check